# Inserting bold characters in pyGTK's TextView/TextBuffer

Tags: python, pygtk, textview, gtk-textbuffer

I have a TextView and a TextBuffer associated with it.

When the user presses Ctrl+b, I would like the text to be start typing in bold until user presses Ctrl+b again.

I was trying my own methods, which weren't working, and then I found this post on the mailing list:
http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2009-April/016951.html

Same issue as me, and the solution someone gave is

> Your application will have to handle the bookkeeping required to manage
> the tags in the TextBuffer. When text is inserted at the cursor your app
> has to catch a signal indicating the text is being inserted and then
> apply the required tags to the inserted text. I think this can be done
> by catching theTextBuffer  "insert-text" signal (using connect_after()
> to make sure the text has already been inserted) and then applying the
> tags to the text in the callback.

So I attempted this. This is my textbuffer.py

```
import gtk
import pango

class TextBuffer(gtk.TextBuffer):
 def __init__(self):
  gtk.TextBuffer.__init__(self)
  self.connect_after('insert-text', self.text_inserted)
  # A list to hold our active tags
  self.tags_on = []
  # Our Bold tag.
  self.tag_bold = self.create_tag("bold", weight=pango.WEIGHT_BOLD) 

 def get_iter_position(self):
  return self.get_iter_at_mark(self.get_insert())
 
 def make_bold(self, text):
  ''' add "bold" to our active tags list '''
  self.tags_on.append('bold')
 
 def text_inserted(self, buffer, iter, text, length):
  # A text was inserted in the buffer. If there are ny tags in self.tags_on, apply them
  if self.tags_on:
   print self.get_iter_position()
   
   # This sets the iter back N characters
   iter.backward_chars(length)
   
   # And this applies tag from iter to end of buffer
   self.apply_tag_by_name('bold', self.get_iter_position(), self.get_end_iter())
   
   print self.get_iter_position()
```

the method make_bold() gets called from the main script whenever someone pressed Ctrl+b.

Theoretically, this is doing precisely what the mailing help said to do. But is not working. Text is not showing up bold as i type. If i press left arrow and move the cursor back, and then type a character, then the characters from the right of cursor tuns bold.

How can I accomplish this task?

Also, could someone add the tag 'textbuffer' to this? I cannot create new tags and I feel like that tag is more accurate than 'textview'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sample code you make the call to `iter.backward_chars` in `TextBuffer.text_inserted` 
but you never use that iter!, so I make a sample script to show you desired behavior and clarify:

```
import gtk
import pango

class TextBuffer(gtk.TextBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.TextBuffer.__init__(self)
        self.connect_after('insert-text', self.text_inserted)
        # A list to hold our active tags
        self.tags_on = []
        # Our Bold tag.
        self.tag_bold = self.create_tag("bold", weight=pango.WEIGHT_BOLD)  

    def get_iter_position(self):
        return self.get_iter_at_mark(self.get_insert())

    def make_bold(self):
        ''' add "bold" to our active tags list '''
        if 'bold' in self.tags_on:
            del self.tags_on[self.tags_on.index('bold')]
        else:
            self.tags_on.append('bold')

    def text_inserted(self, buffer, iter, text, length):
        # A text was inserted in the buffer. If there are ny tags in self.tags_on,   apply them
        if self.tags_on:
            # This sets the iter back N characters
            iter.backward_chars(length)
            # And this applies tag from iter to end of buffer
            self.apply_tag_by_name('bold', self.get_iter_position(), iter)



def main():
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.connect('destroy', lambda _: gtk.main_quit())
    window.resize(300, 300)
    tb = TextBuffer()
    tv = gtk.TextView(buffer=tb)

    accel = gtk.AccelGroup()
    accel.connect_group(gtk.keysyms.b,
                        gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK,gtk.ACCEL_LOCKED,
                        lambda a,b,c,d: tb.make_bold())
    window.add_accel_group(accel)
    window.add(tv)
    window.show_all()
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```